# Django query exception __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'hints'

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I'm pretty new to Django/Python and having a bit of trouble sorting this out.

Ubuntu 14.04
Apache
Django 1.7.4
python 2.7
Postgresql

```
__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'hints'
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://localhost/
Django Version: 1.7.4
Exception Type: TypeError

class Tier(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class Recipe(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(auto_add=True, primary_key=True, default=uuid.uuid4)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    tier = models.ForeignKey(Tier)
```

Here is the code being executed, errors on trying to retrieve the tier id.

```
firstRecipe = Recipe.objects.first()
tierId = firstRecipe.tier.id
```

My database tables are

```
web_recipe
    id
    name
    tier_id

web_tier
    id
    name
```

Stacktrace

```
    Traceback:
File "/home/user123/daoresources/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  111.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/home/user123/daoresources/web/views.py" in index
  7.    firstRecipe = Recipe.objects.first()
File "/home/user123/daoresources/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py" in manager_method
  92.                 return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
File "/home/user123/daoresources/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py" in first
  508.         qs = self if self.ordered else self.order_by('pk')
File "/home/user123/daoresources/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py" in order_by
  812.         obj = self._clone()
File "/home/user123/daoresources/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py" in _clone
  955.         c = klass(model=self.model, query=query, using=self._db, hints=self._hints)

Exception Type: TypeError at /
Exception Value: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'hints'
```

Environment:

```
Django Version: 1.7.4
Python Version: 2.7.6
Installed Applications:
('web', 'django_pg')
Installed Middleware:
('django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware')
```

EDIT: I ended up just saying screw it and converted my project over to mysql and everything works fine. If someone comes up with an valid answer I will test it on a new formed project and mark it as correct.

Answer (score 1):

Install the latest version of django-pgfields from git. It fixed it for me.

If you install from requirements file then remove 'django-pgfields' and add

```
-e git://github.com/lukesneeringer/django-pgfields.git#egg=django-pgfields
```

Comment: Did it get fixed within the past couple of days? Someone already posted this as an answer and it didn't work, but he deleted his answer because it didn't get accepted. I'll try it again here in a little while.

Comment: Don't know when it was fixed. But it fixed it for me to update it like this.

Comment: We ran into a related issue with the django-hstore. The latest stable release of it fixes this same issue. It seems likely that any packages relying on PostgreSQL extensions might need looking into for Django >= 1.7 updates